# Bash: how do I pipe stdout and stderr of one process to two different processes?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

I have a process `myProcess1` that produces both stdout and stderr outputs. I want to pipe the two output streams into two different downstream processes,  `myProcess2` and `myProcess3`, that will massage the data and then dump the results into two different files. Is it possible to do it with a single command? If not, the 2nd best would be running two separate commands, one to process `stdout`, the other `stderr`. In this case, the first run would simply be:

```
myProcess1 | myProcess2 > results-out.txt
```

What would be a similar command to process `stderr`? Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without fancy games something like this should work:

```
{ myProcess1 | myProcess2 > results-out.txt; } 2>&1 | myprocess3 > results-err.txt
```

With fancy games (which do not work in `/bin/sh`, etc.) you could do something like this:

```
myProcess1 2> >(myprocess3 > results-err.txt) | myProcess2 > results-out.txt
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that the second command requires `bash` and will not work with `sh` because of the process substitution.

Comment: The first one assumes that myProcess2 doesn't have any stderr output of its own.  If it does then it will end up being merged in with myProcess1's stderr and passed to myprocess3.

Comment: If `myProcess2` also writes something to stderr, it will end up in `myprocess3` input. To fix this, command should be like `{ myProcess1 2>&3 | myProcess2 > results-out.txt; } 3>&1 | myprocess3 > results-err.txt`

Comment: @Roman True. Alternatively closing `stderr` from `myprocess2` if it isn't desired and/or explicitly redirecting it to standard output or the tty.

Answer (score 2):

A named pipe or two would work well for this, but you'll probably find it easiest to do with multiple terminal windows.

In one terminal window:

```
mknod stdout.pipe p
mknod stderr.pipe p
myProcess1 > stdout.pipe 2> stderr.pipe
```

In a second window:

```
myProcess2 < stdout.pipe
```

And in a third:

```
myProcess3 < stderr.pipe
```

Using background processes and some other tricks, you *could* do it all in one window, but keeping the output of your secondary processes separated would be another challenge...

You could eliminate one of the named pipes (and thus one of the extra windows) with either of these:

```
myProcess1 2> stderr.pipe | myProcess2
```

or

```
{ myProcess1 > stdout.pipe; } 2>&1 | myProcess3
```